# How to detect if a string is within resource file

Tags: c#, string

How do I detect if a string is contained within a .resx file ?

I know I can create a list of all my strings in the .resx file and then use `Contains` function to see if my string is part of that, but is there an easier way ? I have lots of string in the said .resx file and more to be added in the future, so it seems to be a lot of maintenance.

```
var text = "hello";
var resourceList = new List<string> 
{
    // All my resource strings
    CharacterEntities.word1, // "hello"
    CharacterEntities.word2, // "to"
    CharacterEntities.word3, // "Stack"
    CharacterEntities.word4  // "Overflow"
}

var isContained = resources.Contains(text);
```

## edit

I need to check a string if it contains a particular string (all the particular strings are in `CharacterEntities`).

I would like to avoid creating `resourceList` List and work directly with my resource file `CharacterEntities.resx`

Comment: 2 ways. resources.IndexOf("WhatToSearchFor") which will look for a literal match and will return the index it was found. Or you can use Linq to search for similar strings. isContained = resources.Where(res => res.Contains("_substring_")).Any();

Comment: I updated my question. My issue is not using the list, but avoid it. I would like to use directly my resource file which already contains all info needed.

Comment: I that makes sense. I haven't used resx a whole lot, this link seems to have some useful information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I discovered when searching [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources?view=netframework-4.8) on how to work with resx file directly:

First, you can make one up via `System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter` in the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly:

```
var resxPath = @"some\path\here.resx";

using (var resx = new ResXResourceWriter(resxPath)) {
    resx.AddResource("res1", "A resource");
    resx.AddResource("res2", "Another resource");
    resx.AddResource("res3", "Yet another resource");
}
```

If your intention with 'text' is to find if a key exists in the resx file, then you can use `ResXResourceReader`:

```
var key = "res2";
var keyExists = false;

using (var resx = new ResXResourceReader(resxPath)) 
    foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in resx)
        if(entry.Key.ToString() == key)
            keyExists = true;

Console.WriteLine(keyExists); // True
```

If your intention is to find out which keys have your text, you can do this:

```
var text = "other";
var keysHavingText = new List<string>();

using (var resx = new ResXResourceReader(resxPath)) 
    foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in resx)
        if(entry.Value.ToString().Contains(text))
            keysHavingText.Add(entry.Key.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",keysHavingText)); // res2,res3
```

Which, of course, to answer your question as to whether the text is in the resx file at all, you can just look at whether the variable has any entries or not:

```
var isContained = keysHavingText.Count > 0; 
Console.WriteLine(isContained); // True
```

**Edited, but just to pluralize logic for keys having text.**

Comment: Do I absolutely have to create a resx file via code ? I liked the option to create it with the UI and some persons less experienced may have issues adding resources if they want to do it by themselves.

I'm trying your method, package is downloading

Comment: No, that's just to make my example reproducible.  That way users deciding on the quality of this question or searching it for trying to solve their own problems can test it out for themselves.  It also gives a more complete exposition of the assembly in general.  But in your case, you're not expected to create it at all. You're expected to point it to wherever you're storing your existing resx file.